# Django 1.6: Cant modify model in view

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying add a like and dislike count to a doctor object, but it doesn't seem to make any changes to the doctor model. The view is for a form which successfully saves data in another model. But nothing happens to the doctor model. The entire view works fine except the lines with doctor likes, dislikes and netlikes doesn't seem to make any changes. All three of them are fields in the doctor model.

```
def addContent(request, id):
    d = getVariables(request)
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        ds = DoctorSeeker.objects.get(user=user)
        d['doctorseeker'] = ds


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserContentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            time = form.cleaned_data['time']
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

            if request.POST.get('Like') == 'Like':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = True, disliked = False, doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.likes += 1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                con.save()

            elif request.POST.get('Like') == 'Dislike':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = False, disliked = True,  doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.dislikes +=1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                con.save()

            url = '/docprofile/%s' % str(doctor.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
        form = UserContentForm()

    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'UGC': UserContent.objects.all(),
          'form': form })
    return render(request, 'meddy1/usercontent.html',d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save the doctor instance anywhere.

```
doctor.dislikes += 1
doctor.save()
```

(You may also consider whether you actually need to store 'netlikes' in a field: it may be better to have it as a simple method on the model, which just returns `self.likes - self.dislikes`.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use F() expressions for handling likes and disliked. It will increment them at the database level instead of getting an outdated value from memory. Here is the link to the official documentation on [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions)

So the code would look something like this

```
doctor.dislikes = F('dislikes') + 1
doctor.save()
```